# Theorem : If the moment of order t exists for an RV X, moments of order 0 < s < t exist.

Tags: probability, random-variables

An Introduction to probability and statistics - Rohatgi Pg. No. 74 Theorem 2

Theorem : If the moment of order $t$ exists for an RV $X$, moments of order $0 < s < t$ exist.

The proof is given in the text.

I am not able to understand the proof. He uses a notation $|x|^s \leqslant 1$ in integral that I am not aware. Can someone help me understand the proof.

Also, I find Rohatgi really high level, but since my instructor follows this book, I am stuck with reading this book. Are there any good books that explains things a bit more and in line with Rohatgi's contents?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to compare $|X|^s$ and $|X|^t$: if $|X(\omega)|\geqslant 1$, then $|X(\omega)|^s\leqslant|X(\omega)|^t$, so $\mathbb E[|X|^s\chi_{\{|X|\geqslant 1\}}]$ is convergent. The integration over the set $\{|X(\omega)|\lt 1\}$ is not problematic as $|X|^s$ is bounded.